# SQL select does not return any entries

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I am using a Sql query to load a subset of data

```
SELECT [sfb_id]
      ,[prs_id_201304]
      ,[prs_id_201204]
      ,[vorname]
      ,[sex]
  FROM [IAB\KruegerJ049].[test]
  WHERE sex='Weiblich'
```

the column `sex` contains the characters `Männlich` or `Weiblich` (male or female). I only want to read out rows which contain `sex='Weiblich'`. But this code does not return any entries!

Thanks in advance

Comment: contain the value or equal to the value ? that's different !

Comment: Show some example data please

Comment: Does your query run properly?

Comment: Does the code work if you remove the WHERE clause?

Comment: Ja the query runs and gives no error. Without where it works.

Answer (score 0):

It may be your collation is not right. change the collation and repeat the query . there is not error on your query.

Comment: It is more a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try `WHERE sex LIKE '%Weiblich%'` in case there are some spaces before or after.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it with babysteps. First check should be if

```
SELECT *  FROM [IAB\KruegerJ049].[test]
```

returns entrys, then try

```
SELECT *  FROM [IAB\KruegerJ049].[test] WHERE sex='Weiblich'
```

i think you misstyped something :) you can also try

```
WHERE sex LIKE '*Weiblich*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(LOWER(sex))) = 'weiblich'